# Find the number of positive integers n between $1$ and $100$ that are not a multiple of $3$ or $11$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Find the number of positive integers n between $1$ and $100$ that are not a multiple of $3$ or $11$.

**My Try:**

Numbers divisible $3$ between $1$ and $100=33$  (set A)

Numbers divisible $11$ between $1$ and $100=9$  (set B)

Numbers divisible $3$ and $11$ between $1$ and $100=2$  (set A and B)

A U B = A + B + A and B

A U B $= 33 + 9 + 3 = 45$

The numbers that are not divisible by $3$ and $11$ between $1$ and $100$ are $100-45=55$.

But the given answer is $61$

Can anyone show where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that there was a typo, and you meant to put $|A \cap B| = 3$ and not $2$, in both places.

Your main problem is that you've applied the principle of inclusion and exclusion incorrectly, and

$$
|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = 33 + 9 - 3 = 39
$$

and not $33 + 9 + 3 = 45$.  After that, you should obtain the correct answer.